# I can't get a response from the server via socket python

Tags: python, sockets

```
  import socket

  with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as socket_server:

    socket_server.connect(("77.222.42.207", 1337))
    socket_server.send("get_flag".encode())

    server_unswer = (socket_server.recv(1024)).decode()
    print(server_unswer)

    while (messsage := input("Я: ")) != "exit":
      socket_server.send(messsage.encode())
      messsage = socket_server.recv(1024)
      messsage = messsage.decode()
      print(messsage)
```

I'm trying to send a string to the server, but I can't send the data and get a response, what's the problem, please help.

When I connect to the server via netcat, everything is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as socket_server:

  socket_server.connect(("77.222.42.207", 1337))

  server_unswer = (socket_server.recv(1024)).decode()
  print(server_unswer)

  socket_server.send("get_flag\n".encode())

  server_unswer = (socket_server.recv(1024)).decode()
  print(server_unswer)
```

I was finally able to get a response from the server, it was because NetCat automatically adds \n when sending text and the command on the server worked, but I did not add this character when sending text

I had to figure out how to use Wireshark to figure it out)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like nothing is wrong with your code.Just create a simple server as shown below and connect your client socket program.

```
import socket
server = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_STREAM,             
proto=socket.IPPROTO_TCP, fileno=None)
server.bind(('IP address', port))
server.listen(10)
client, _ = server.accept()
    # Instead of a infinite while loop a for loop in given with a count of 10
    for i in range(10):
        data = client.recv(65535).decode()
        print(data)
        client.send(data.encode())
server.close()
```

Obviously you will have to update **socket_server.connect(("77.222.42.207", 1337))**

Comment: You seem to misunderstand my problem, I need to get the flag by sending the get_flag string after connecting to the server, not waiting for a connection to my PC from this server.

Comment: I don't think so. I completly understand that you are trying to connect to a server with your client programme.The code I have given in my answer is a simple server programme.You can use this code to test tour client programme,. Save that code in a file and run and connect to this server with your client programme. Since this is for testing your code and assuming that you will test on your local machine, use the loopback address in your programme as well as in the server programme. I have checked it mnyself and found out that your client programme works.

Comment: I already tested the client program before I asked the question on Stackoverflow and with your server program everything works fine too, I just can't understand why the server 77.222.42.207:1337 doesn't respond to my program messages and Netcat does.

Comment: Then the best option for you is to use WireShark and inspect the packets between netcat and the server and also with between your programme and the server.